# Canonical Forms of Jordan

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Given the matrix $A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
 0&  2&-\frac{1}{2} \\ 
 2& 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &-2 
\end{matrix} \right )$.

How can I calculate $e^{A}$ using the Canonical Forms of Jordan?.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like a question for an instructor or TA.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{0, 2, -1/2}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2}};
{s, j} = JordanDecomposition@m;
s.MatrixExp[j].Inverse@s == MatrixExp[m] // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```